# How to use calloc and snprintf

Tags: c, printf, calloc

I'd like to use calloc and snprintf.
Can you review my simple code and tell me how to fix it?
I kept having an error that Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFB8A2D1F0.
Thank you!

```
int main()
{
 
    char* buffer1;

    buffer1 = (char*)calloc(1, 14);

    int a = 15;
    int b = 25;
    char c[]="MON"

    int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully please fix this simple code.

Comment: How many letters are in "MON"?

Comment: Also look very closely at your format string: `"%02d%02%s"`. You're also missing a `;` after `"MON"`.

Comment: @tadman Oh that should be char c[4]="MON", makes sense?

Comment: Do `#include <stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`

Comment: The original definition is fine. I thought you were expecting 2 characters in your (slightly broken) formatter string. Whenever possible in C, let the compiler figure out how large the buffer should be.

Comment: @pmg Yep definitely but still not working

Comment: You have 3 `%` in your format string, but only 2 valid conversions.

Comment: Don't run code that has compiler warnings, and then wonder why it fails. No warnings? Enable them.

Comment: Don't edit the question in a way that removes the problem you are asking about!

Comment: 1) `snprintf` will already account for the null byte at the end of the string, you can safely give it the full buffer size: `snprintf(buffer1, 14, "%02d%02d%s", a, b, c);` 2) There's no need here to zero out the memory in buffer1; `calloc` is not necessary here, `malloc` will work fine.

Comment: @Schwern: "`malloc` will work fine" ... provided `<stdlib.h>` has been included! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // <string.h> not needed

int main(void)
{
    char* buffer1;
    buffer1 = calloc(1, 14); // cast not needed
    if (!buffer1) { fprintf(stderr, "Memory Failure.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    int a = 15;
    int b = 25;
    char c[4] = "MON";

    int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02d%s", a, b, c);
    //                    --------------- ^ ---------------
    printf("k is %d; buffer1 has [%s]\n", k, buffer1);

    free(buffer1); // release resources no longer needed

    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/WMtMQt

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't compile.

```
source>:21:5: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'int'
   21 |     int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);
      |     ^~~
```

Let's fixed that.

Still, the fixed code has numerous warnings.

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:21:42: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]
   21 |     int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);
      |                                          ^
<source>:21:44: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   21 |     int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);
      |                                           ~^      ~
      |                                            |      |
      |                                            char * int
      |                                           %d
<source>:21:35: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   21 |     int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:21:9: warning: unused variable 'k' [-Wunused-variable]
   21 |     int k = snprintf(buffer1, 13, "%02d%02%s", a, b, c);
```

The issue is the missing `d` in the format string.

ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings and hede them. With gcc, you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`.

Comment: This is not a point of the error actually. I have just fixed typos but it still has an error.

Comment: Can you try to copy and paste the code I have fixed again?

Comment: You're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. Again, ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings.

Comment: I appreciate it!